# Understanding of Automorphism

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$, $Y$ be two ordered sets. If $X=Y$, then instead of isomorphism we speak of automorphism.

My question is what does this $X=Y$ mean? Can be this number of elements of sets?

Comment: 1. $X = Y$ means that $X$ equals $Y$. That is, they're the same set. 2. Are you sure you don't mean "automorphism" instead of "outomorphism"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks. Of course, automorphism.

Comment: I think my comment above essentially answers the question, but in the interest of having this question marked as "answered" instead of "unanswered", I've converted it into a actual answer below.

Comment: It means everything: the underlying set, and the ordering on it, are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, $X = Y$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are the same object. In your context of ordered sets, they're the same ordered set, i.e. the same set with the same order.

It looks like this arose in the context of defining the terms isomorphism and automorphism. An *automorphism* is a map from an object to itself, i.e. $f\colon X\to X$ (or equivalently $f\colon X\to Y$ where $X = Y$) which is an isomorphism.